# Python27 Django application deployment on Elastic beanstalk "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported"

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, importerror

This question has been raised partially couple of times but every provided solution doesn't seem to fix my problem. Can anyone please help, I've spent many hours trying to figure out the problem.

Let me share the directory structure and wsgi.py, manage.py code

**directory structure** (Only showing necessary files below to explain directory structure)

```
app_pro
    .ebextensions
        01_packages.config
        django.config
        setup_packages.sh
    .elasticbeanstalk
        config.yml
    myapp
        apps
        logs
        templates
        myapp
            __init__.py
            settings
                production.py
                local.py
                eb_settings.py
                base.py
            url.py
            wsgi.py
        manage.py
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
import sys
settings = "myapp.settings.eb_settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings)
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.eb_settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**django.config**

```
option_settings:
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 
    "/opt/python/current/app/app_pro/myapp/myapp/settings/eb_settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/app_pro/myapp:$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": "*"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "/opt/python/current/app/app_pro/myapp/collectstatic/"
```

And this is the error I've been keep getting.

```
Application update failed at 2018-06-01T08:46:59Z with exit status 1 and error: container_command 03_migrate in app_pro/.ebextensions/01_packages.config failed.
myapp.settings.eb_settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/ondeck/app/app_pro/myapp/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

What could be the source of the problem?

Comment: Try using the `myapp.settings.eb_settings` instead of `"/opt/python/current/app/app_pro/myapp/myapp/settings/eb_settings"`. It also looks as if your wsgi file is missing the `myapp.` prefix in `myapp.settings.eb_settings`.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair I have tried that, but it doesn't work. :'(

Comment: If that gives you the exact same error, then I don’t have any other suggestions. If it gives you a different error, then you need to show that error. You could try reverting to a simple `mysite/settings.py` and try to get that to work instead of having a `settings.py` directory.